# Boundary preserving map

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, complex-analysis, differential-geometry

Let $K\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$ be a compact set. Is it true that for a continuous map $p:K\to\mathbb{R}^2$ we have:

$p(\partial K)=\partial p(K)$? Are there any generalizations?

P.S. Note that $\partial X$ is the boundary of $X$.

Comment: When we assume more about both f and X and we get a positive answer: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/253930/does-isometric-immersion-map-boundary-to-boundary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, consider $p(re^{it}) = (\sin r )e^{it}.$ Then $p$ maps $K = \overline {D(0,3\pi /4)}$ onto $\overline {D(0,1)}$ but $p(\partial K)$ doesn't even intersect $\partial (p(K)).$